# how implement Owin pipeline using Asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, owin

indeed you can't use third-party tools such as OData, Thinktecture Identity Server, ... in asp.net core application.
So, how we can use these features in asp.net core apps ?
is there any way to implement Owin pipeline beside asp core and have all these facilities too ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

easily you can use Owin pipeline beside Asp.net core, not as an alternative solution.
in this article there is a simple way to implement this architecture using Owin and asp.net core
[Implement Owin pipeline using Asp.net Core](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1122162/Implement-Owin-Pipeline-using-Asp-net-Core)

Comment: Could you summarise the article, so that your answer is more useful even if the external resource is unavailable?

Comment: in fact tooling such as OData,.. has not been released in Asp.net core pipeline version, So to have this we should implement Owin standard beside asp core, aftre that in your application you can have owin middlewares beside asp core middlewares and they work together properly.  cause of owin midWares you can use owin compatible tools have not released for asp core. it means your old codes works fine in asp core. just take care that in this way you should use full .Net framework not .net core and you miss cross platform app,
but after the release of these features, easily lay away full .Net